# Unable to find "Button" with Selenium in C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I have got a problem with Selenium code to find a button which has only `"Value"` and `"type"`, in inspection it looks like this:

```
<input type="sumbit" value="login" />
```

[Image of inspection](https://ibb.co/6PVbQsw)

I tried twice but neither line worked for me.

The lines:

1st solution:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[contains(text(),'Login')]")).Click();
```

2nd solution:

```
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("submit")).Click();
```

[Image with ERROR MESSAGE (second line error)](https://ibb.co/0cVf4Qg)

Can anybody help me, or at least point out what am I missing, because its getting pretty frustrating to find a solution for such common thing, I practiced this on tutorial pages and buttons were never a problem.

Please. (Sorry for my English)

P.s.: I checked the "similar questions and I haven't found the solution.

P.s.s: Guys, there is another one which I didnt try yet but I have 3 different lines of code, do you think one of them will work:

There is drop-down list and I want to select the last thing in the list...

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(., 'Process Data >>')]"));

driver.FindElement(By.Id("pdatasub")).Click();

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[text()='Process Data >>']")).Click();

[Inspection of the Drop-down list](https://ibb.co/NjntVb6)

Code for the opening of the last "button" in the drop-down list:

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[text()='Final Values']")).Click();

[enter link description here](https://ibb.co/w45HqQc)

Thanks guys for help !

Comment: Can you share a link to that page?

Comment: Which page ? Becuase the one I am trying to do is inside a machine, I am trying to do a project where I connect to the machine via ethernet, load page with setup which is obtained by IP and then I want to login and download backup. All this automatically but sadly I got stuck during the login process.

Comment: OK. Can you share the HTML code of the entire page. The login page, if problems are there.

Comment: I just added another part in the main post, I could try to do that tomorrow, since the PLC is at work and I dont have connection from home. :(

Answer (score 1):

Your locator is wrong.
You can use this:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@type='submit']")).Click();
```

or

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@value='login']")).Click();
```

or

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@value='login' and @type='submit']")).Click();
```

CSS Selector can be used as well similarly.
Also there are several possible issues:

1. You should add a wait before accessing that element. Otherwise you are trying to find an element while page is still not loaded. Expected conditions are the preferred way to do this with.
2. The element can be inside an iframe. If so you have to switch to that iframe in order to access elements inside it.

Comment: There are Thread.Sleep(1000) after every line of code in there. Thanks for the help !

Comment: OK, have you tried to use locators / code as I wrote here?

Comment: I will, since I have to connect directly to the machine I will be able to try this tomorrow at work, since , sadly, I dont have the PLC with me at home. (to be honest I didnt know I would get answer so quickly, you guys here are way too nice)
I added steps which I have ahead since you were so quick with the response I just wanted to double check if the next step will be viable.

Comment: driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@type='submit']")).Click();
This one didnt work.

Comment: What about the other options? What exception does it throw?

Comment: Ok today I tried all three options, neither worked. :/ Damn I am doing something wrong or I dont know. . .

Comment: Well... Need to see that page HTML myself with dev tools.

Comment: can you inspect the element and right click on the html of the element through chrome and select "Copy xpath" and please post that in here?

Comment: @damiensprinkle not sure this will help us.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong locator  :

try this instead :

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@type='submit' and @value='Login']")).Click();
```

or

With `ExplicitWaits`

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//input[@type='submit' and @value='Login']"))).Click();
```

Comment: Thanks ! I will try that. :)

Comment: When you tried this `driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@type='submit' and @value='Login']")).Click();` what exception did you see ?